# Variables declaration in Babel-node

Tags: javascript, node.js, ecmascript-6, babeljs

I'm using babel-node for execute this simple statement:

```
let obj = {};
```

But when i run, the following error appears:

```
SyntaError: repl: Only 'var' variables are supported in repl
```

I tried to run 'var' rather than 'let', but it appeared :

```
undefined
```

then i cannot access the variable

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because when using the `babel-node` [repl](http://babeljs.io/docs/usage/cli/#usage) you must load the [presets](http://babeljs.io/docs/plugins/preset-es2015/) of your choice to activate their respective es2015 features.

To do so you need to run:

```
npm install babel-preset-es2015
```

Then when booting up the babel repl, you'll have to specify the presets:

```
babel-node --presets es2015
```

Now you can then use `let obj = {}`

Regarding the `undefined` output, `babel-node` and even the `node` repl, this is expected and default behavior. Per the node [REPL docs](https://nodejs.org/api/repl.html#repl_repl_start_options):

`ignoreUndefined` - if set to `true`, then the repl will not output the return value of command if it's `undefined`. Defaults to `false`.

This means that any anytime you invoke something in the repl, `undefined` is returned.